# labeling a legend in epplus

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, epplus

I'm trying to create a graph from some data I export to an .xls file.  I create the graph just fine, but I'm going to have anywhere from 3 - 7 lines on the graph.  I added the legend to make it easier to read, but the legend has no text on it.  It just shows a line without a label.  Is there anyway to label the legend key?

Here's the code of the graph I'm making:

```
    var lineChart = ws.Drawings.AddChart(item.TestHeader, eChartType.Line) as ExcelLineChart;
    lineChart.SetSize(800, 400);

    lineChart.Series.Add(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(65 + distanceCount + 1).ToString() + "1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(65 + distanceCount + 1).ToString() + (testCount.ToString()), "A1:A" + (testCount.ToString()));

    lineChart.Title.Text = item.TestHeader;
    lineChart.DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = true;
    lineChart.DataLabel.ShowLegendKey = true;
    lineChart.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
    lineChart.XAxis.Title.Text = "Inches from Decoder";
    lineChart.YAxis.Title.Text = "Milliseconds to decode";
    lineChart.YAxis.MaxValue = 1000;
```

Any help is better than none, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example generated a series name in the legend for me named "Series". But you can set it explicitly using

```
lineChart.Series[0].Header = "Series 1 Name";
```